# Why am I getting error 'GetTempPathA': is not a member of 'System::IO::Path'

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I have a managed c++/CLI project and am working in VS2019. When I enter the line:

```
String^ TempPath = System::IO::Path::GetTempPath();
```

I get the error shown in the title. What is expanding my method call, and why is VS2019 'expanding' it to a method that doesn't exist?

[Error box displayed when I hover my mouse over the GetTempPath() call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7iSm.png)

Comment: Note the extra A.  Caused by a macro in windows.h.  Put `#undef GetTempPathA` after the #include to kill it dead.

Answer (score 3):

I knew where the 'A' was coming from. I just assumed that Visual Studio would NOT apply the macro to a .NET framework class method. (I was wrong!)

The fix is to put `#undef GetTempPath` ahead of the method call.

(Thank you to @Hans Passant for the answer to my question.)